# Using 0x39FE001E (PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) in AdvancedSearch?

Tags: vba, outlook, vsto

I'm trying the search for emails based on SMTP address. I've found that I need to use `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E` but if I try to create a view using the following DASL filter, nothing is displayed:

> "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E" = 'name@domain.com'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to do it like this:

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E" CI_STARTSWITH 'name@domain.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

No messages have `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` property set directly on them. It is only set on the address book objects or in the message recipient table.

Are you trying to filter based on the sender SMTP address? `PidTagSenderSmtpAddress` may or may not be present (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F`)c - try to use it instead.

Check if you can see that property in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMessage button).